# Get up to speed with algorithms

Tags: algorithms

Does anyone have any advice about how I can fast track my understanding of what these types of algorithms mean:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)

I don't want to have to sit 3 years of maths but is there anything I can do for this to make more sense?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without more knowledge, and even then the answer would most likely be only useful for you. That does not make this a good question for SE as a platform. I recommend you drop by in [chat] which is more suited for this kind of issue.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't have said they were *algorithms* per se, more a collection of transformations.

If you want to get a theoretical viewpoint on monads, I'd suggest picking up a category theory textbook. You don't need to do "3 years of maths" to understand one, just some set theory (probably) and some dedication.

On the other hand, if you'd prefer a practical handle, I'd learn the Haskell programming language, which uses monads extensively to represent certain types of side-effects. "Learn You a Haskell" is very good. Try and avoid the infamous "monad tutorials" which inevitably over-simplify in order to produce an analogy. I think just reading the monad typeclass, then looking at examples is probably the best advice.